How can I make my proxy server intercept and forward https trrafic too and can I block https websites too (like youtube.com)
I am working on a http proxy in Python with blocking websites functionality and logging. It works fine but it works only with http and not with https. I try it to make it work with the ssl library and creating a self signed key with openssl but no luck. I don't know how to go about it.
Here is the code
import socket
import signal
import threading
import logging
from datetime import datetime

class ProxyServer:

    def __init__(self, config):
        # Shutdown on Ctrl+C
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.shutdown) 

        # Create a TCP socket
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Re-use the socket
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        # Bind the socket to a public host, and a port   
        self.serverSocket.bind((config['HOST_NAME'], config['BIND_PORT']))
        
        self.serverSocket.listen(10) # Become a server socket
        self.__clients = {}

        self.config = config

        # Setup logging
        logging.basicConfig(filename=config['LOG_FILE'], level=logging.INFO, 
                            format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        # Blocklist
        self.blocklist = config.get('BLOCKLIST',[])

    def shutdown(self, signum, frame):
        print("Shutting down server...")
        self.serverSocket.close()
        exit(0)

    def _getClientName(self, client_address):
        return f"{client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}"

    def proxy_thread(self, clientSocket, client_address):
        # Get the request from the browser
        request = clientSocket.recv(self.config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN'])

        # Log the request
        self.log_request(request, client_address)

        # Parse the first line
        first_line = request.split(b'\n')[0]

        # Get URL
        url = first_line.split(b' ')[1].decode('utf-8')
        http_pos = url.find("://") # Find pos of ://
        if http_pos == -1:
            temp = url
        else:
            temp = url[(http_pos+3):] # Get the rest of URL

        port_pos = temp.find(":") # Find the port pos (if any)

        # Find end of web server
        webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
        if webserver_pos == -1:
            webserver_pos = len(temp)

        webserver = ""
        port = -1
        if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos: 
            # Default port 
            port = 80 
            webserver = temp[:webserver_pos] 
        else: # Specific port 
            port = int((temp[(port_pos+1):])[:webserver_pos-port_pos-1])
            webserver = temp[:port_pos]

        # Check if the domain is in the blocklist
        if self.is_blocked(webserver):
            self.deny_request(clientSocket, webserver)
            return

        try:
            # Create a socket to connect to the web server
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
            s.settimeout(self.config['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'])
            s.connect((webserver, port))
            s.sendall(request)

            while True:
                data = s.recv(self.config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN'])
                if len(data) > 0:
                    clientSocket.send(data)
                else:
                    break
        except socket.error as e:
            print(f"Socket error: {e}")
        finally:
            clientSocket.close()
            s.close()

    def is_blocked(self, domain):
        return any(blocked_domain in domain for blocked_domain in self.blocklist)

    def deny_request(self, clientSocket, domain):
        response = (
        "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<html>"
        "<head>"
        "<style>"
        "body {"
        "  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"
        "  background-color: #FF0000;"
        "  display: flex;"
        "  justify-content: center;"
        "  align-items: center;"
        "  height: 100vh;"
        "  margin: 0;"
        "}"
        "h1 {"
        "  color: #333;"
        "  font-size: 36px;"
        "  margin-bottom: 20px;"
        "}"
        "p {"
        "  color: #666;"
        "  font-size: 18px;"
        "}"
        ".container {"
        "  background-color: #fff;"
        "  padding: 40px;"
        "  border-radius: 8px;"
        "  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);"
        "  text-align: center;"
        "}"
        "</style>"
        "</head>"
        "<body>"
        "<div class='container'>"
        "<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>"
        f"<p>Access to {domain} is blocked.</p>"
        "</div>"
        "</body>"
        "</html>"
        )
        clientSocket.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
        clientSocket.close()
        logging.info(f"Blocked access to {domain}")

    def log_request(self, request, client_address):
        request_lines = request.decode('utf-8', errors='replace').split('\n')
        log_message = f"Source IP: {client_address[0]}\n"

        for line in request_lines:
            log_message += line + "\n"

        logging.info(log_message)

    def start(self):
        while True:
            try:
                # Establish the connection
                clientSocket, client_address = self.serverSocket.accept() 
                
                d = threading.Thread(name=self._getClientName(client_address), 
                                     target=self.proxy_thread, 
                                     args=(clientSocket, client_address))
                d.setDaemon(True)
                d.start()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error:{e}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    blocklist_file=open("blocklist.txt","r")
    blocklist=blocklist_file.read().splitlines()
    blocklist_file.close()
    config = {
        'HOST_NAME': '127.0.0.1',
        'BIND_PORT': 8888,
        'MAX_REQUEST_LEN': 8192,
        'CONNECTION_TIMEOUT': 5,
        'LOG_FILE': 'proxy_server.log',
        'BLOCKLIST': blocklist
    }
    
    server = ProxyServer(config)
    server.start()

I tried to import ssl library and generate a self signed certificate imported it to Firefox but it still can t I still can t visit https website(when I try to visit one it don t load). Here is the modified code side
    def proxy_thread(self, clientSocket, client_address):
        request = clientSocket.recv(self.config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN'])
        self.log_request(request, client_address)
        first_line = request.split(b'\n')[0]
        url = first_line.split(b' ')[1].decode('utf-8')
        http_pos = url.find("://")
        if http_pos == -1:
            temp = url
        else:
            temp = url[(http_pos+3):]
        port_pos = temp.find(":")
        webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
        if webserver_pos == -1:
            webserver_pos = len(temp)
        webserver = ""
        port = -1
        if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos:
            port = 80
            webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]
        else:
            port = int((temp[(port_pos+1):])[:webserver_pos-port_pos-1])
            webserver = temp[:port_pos]
        if self.is_blocked(webserver):
            self.deny_request(clientSocket, webserver)
            return

        try:
            if port == 443:  # HTTPS
                context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
                context.load_cert_chain(certfile='server.crt', keyfile='server.key')
                s = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname=webserver)
            else:  # HTTP
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(self.config['CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'])
            s.connect((webserver, port))
            s.sendall(request)
            while True:
                data = s.recv(self.config['MAX_REQUEST_LEN'])
                if len(data) > 0:
                    clientSocket.send(data)
                else:
                    break
        except socket.error as e:
            print(f"Socket error: {e}")
        except ssl.SSLError as e:
            print(f"SSL error: {e}")
        finally:
            clientSocket.close()
            if 's' in locals():
                s.close()

so as i said what i want is to be able to intercept https traffic too and also block https websites too if possible, Thank you in advance

This is a little unclear still but it looks like you have a misunderstanding of of how HTTPS works. Your proxy_thread method apparently tries to read a plaintext URL first to decide if you are receiving an HTTPS connection. However, HTTPS doesn't work that way. The first thing that happens in HTTPS is that a TLS connection is negotiated with the peer, so that's what your proxy must be able to do.

You also have a misunderstanding of how TCP works. It is a byte steam so you will not always receive a single request in one recv. Buffer the bytes and extract requests following the expected protocol.

i know how https work but only on surface level (i know that tls/ssl encrypt connection) and there is a tls handshake but as i said only from a  surface level (this code was mainly created from the resources' i found online + chatgpt) can you please point me to the right direction (this project was assigned to me in my internship and i didn t think it was that much out of my level i thought with researching + my basic knowledges of socket and threading i could do it but I was wrong now i have to deliver it in 8 days)  , and thank you for your comment
